# How to delete MS Message Queue from Active Directory - Error A queue with the same path name already exists

Tags: active-directory, msmq

I deleted a Public Queue from my local box this morning and then went to recreate the queue.  When I go to recreate it I get the message:
Error: A queue with the same path name already exists

From research it appears that the queue gets replicated in the AD and sometimes it doesn't delete.

So now the AD admin has to delete this for me, but they don't seem to understand.

So how can I get past this error?

I am not sure if this is the best site for this question, but I'm a programmer... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally got this figured out.  When you install MSMQ there is an option for it to integrate with Active Directory. This is on by default, and in my situation was required.

It apparently integrates by mirroring your queue on the AD server under your machine.

Sometimes when you delete a local queue it does not replicate that deletion to the AD server.  When this happens the error will produce itself when you try to re-add the queue.

The fix is to have your AD administrator navigate to the Active Directory Management console and then hit the advanced features and drill down to your computer and remove the Queue in question.  Then you can re-add your queue to your box.

Comment: Thanks for looping back, and letting us know how you resolved the issue.